# Could it be simpler?

Tags: javascript, css

I wrote a little vanilla JavaScript program, but I want to know if there is a possibility to write this simpler? With ES6+? But only with vanila JavaScript, no jQuery or other libraries / frameworks. Thanks in advance for the suggested solutions.

```js
const red = document.getElementById('circleOne');
const green = document.getElementById('circleTwo');
const blue = document.getElementById('circleThree');

red.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  red.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});

red.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
  red.style.backgroundColor = "white";
});

green.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  green.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  red.style.backgroundColor = "green";
});

green.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
  green.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  red.style.backgroundColor = "white";
});

blue.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  green.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  red.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  blue.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
});

blue.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
  green.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  red.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  blue.style.backgroundColor = "white";
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
  max-width: 700px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

section .circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="circleOne" class="circle"></div>
  <div id="circleTwo" class="circle"></div>
  <div id="circleThree" class="circle"></div>
</section>
```

Thanks in advance for the suggested solutions.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad and isn't really a good fit for SO because its working code. The only suggestion I have is to try to factor your event handlers into some common functions, to avoid the repetition.

Comment: you are doing it right. although you can combine all the logic in one function and check event.target if it is red, green or blue

Comment: This question would be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one option: make a function which accepts an array of elements and sets each of their backgrounds, and add a single mouseout listener to the container which sets all to white. No need for IDs, you can put each circle into a variable quickly with `querySelectorAll` and destructuring:

```js
const bgcolorAll = (arr, color) => arr.forEach(elm => elm.style.backgroundColor = color);
const section = document.querySelector('section');
section.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  bgcolorAll([red, green, blue], 'white');
});

const [red, green, blue] = document.querySelectorAll('section > div');

red.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  bgcolorAll([red], 'red');
});

green.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  bgcolorAll([red, green], 'green');
});

blue.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  bgcolorAll([red, green, blue], 'blue');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
  max-width: 700px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

section .circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</section>
```

Or, even more DRY, don't select the individual circles at all, and instead use an array:

```js
const bgcolorAll = (arr, color) => arr.forEach(elm => elm.style.backgroundColor = color);
const section = document.querySelector('section');
const circles = [...document.querySelectorAll('section > div')];
section.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  bgcolorAll(circles, 'white');
});

const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
section.addEventListener('mouseover', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.matches('.circle')) {
    const index = circles.indexOf(target)
    bgcolorAll(
      circles.slice(0, index + 1),
      colors[index]
    );
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
  max-width: 700px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

section .circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</section>
```

You can also achieve this with CSS only:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
  max-width: 700px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'red green blue';
}

section .circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.circle:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: blue;
}
.circle:nth-child(1):hover,
.circle:nth-child(1):hover ~ .circle:nth-child(2),
.circle:nth-child(1):hover ~ .circle:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.circle:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: green;
}
.circle:nth-child(2):hover,
.circle:nth-child(2):hover ~ .circle:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
}

.circle:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: red;
}
.circle:nth-child(3):hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance This is exactly the solution I was looking for. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @LordSauron Also possible with CSS only, see edit (though it's a bit repetitive)

Comment: @CertainPerformance This is brilliant, thank you for this solution too. Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest, DRY, code I could come up with at the spur of the moment

```js
const circles = [...document.querySelectorAll('div.circle')];

circles.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) { // use function not arrow so this is current element
    const color = this.dataset.color;
    circles.some(x => {
      x.style.backgroundColor = color;
      return x === this;
    });
  });
  el.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) { // use function not arrow so this is current element
    circles.some(x => {
      x.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      return x === this;
    });
  });
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
  max-width: 700px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

section .circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="circleOne" class="circle" data-color="red"></div>
  <div id="circleTwo" class="circle" data-color="green"></div>
  <div id="circleThree" class="circle" data-color="blue"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function which takes the dom element, the colour and additionally the other dom elements to change the colour of, and use that to define the two handlers.

```
const red = document.getElementById('circleOne');
const green = document.getElementById('circleTwo');
const blue = document.getElementById('circleThree');

function addCircleListeners(elem, col, ...others) {

    const allElems = [elem, ...others];

    elem.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        allElems.forEach(e => e.style.backgroundColor = col);
    });

    elem.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
        allElems.forEach(e => e.style.backgroundColor = "white");
    });
}

addCircleListeners(red, "red");
addCircleListeners(green, "green", red);
addCircleListeners(blue, "blue", red, green);
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution. I learned from this example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **function composition** approach. This is done by looking over what you're trying to accomplish within your code, point by point, and then builds up functions to facilitate each minor task until the larger task is accomplished.

This approach breaks things down into two distinct parts: **Setup** and **Execution**.

Setup is where you design all your functions and variables, Execution is putting it all to work.

```
// SETUP:

const [ red, green, blue ] = document.querySelectorAll( ".circle" ),

    bg = n => c => n.style.backgroundColor = c,
    colorMatch = ( cs ) => ( fn, i ) => fn( cs[ i ] ? cs[ i ] : cs[ cs.length - 1 ] ),

    bgs = ( ...ns ) => ( ...cs ) => () => ns.map( bg ).map( colorMatch( cs ) ),

    ev = n => t => fn => n.addEventListener( t, () => fn() ),
    mout = n => fn => ev( n )( "mouseout" )( fn ),
    mover = n => fn => ev( n )( "mouseover" )( fn ),

    hover = ( n, {over, out} ) => ( mover( n )( over ), mout( n )( out ) );


// EXECUTION:

hover( red, {
    over: bgs( red )( "red" ),
    out: bgs( red )( "white" )
} );

hover( green, {
    over: bgs( red, green )( "green" ),
    out: bgs( red, green )( "white" )
} );

hover( blue, {
    over: bgs( red, green, blue )( "blue" ),
    out: bgs( red, green, blue )( "white" )
} );
```

---

### Example:

```js
const [ red, green, blue ] = document.querySelectorAll( ".circle" ),

 bg = n => c => n.style.backgroundColor = c,
 colorMatch = ( cs ) => ( fn, i ) => fn( cs[ i ] ? cs[ i ] : cs[ cs.length - 1 ] ),

 bgs = ( ...ns ) => ( ...cs ) => () => ns.map( bg ).map( colorMatch( cs ) ),

 ev = n => t => fn => n.addEventListener( t, () => fn() ),
 mout = n => fn => ev( n )( "mouseout" )( fn ),
 mover = n => fn => ev( n )( "mouseover" )( fn ),

 hover = ( n, {over, out} ) => ( mover( n )( over ), mout( n )( out ) );

hover( red, {
 over: bgs( red )( "red" ),
 out: bgs( red )( "white" )
} );

hover( green, {
 over: bgs( red, green )( "green" ),
 out: bgs( red, green )( "white" )
} );

hover( blue, {
 over: bgs( red, green, blue )( "blue" ),
 out: bgs( red, green, blue )( "white" )
} );
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

section{
    margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
    max-width: 700px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

section .circle{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 0 auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script defer src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <section>
        <div id="circleOne" class="circle"></div>
        <div id="circleTwo" class="circle"></div>
        <div id="circleThree" class="circle"></div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

---

### Additional Info

Two points of note -

1. I would definitely, *definitely* encourage you to not name your circles by their hover colors in your code. It's confusing and isn't really appropriate since the color isn't definitive of the element selected, and it makes the code immeasurably harder harder to read.
2. Though this code will work, be aware that if this isn't within a scope all these variables will become global. This is not ideal. I would take care to place the variables *within* a smaller scope( into an object or something ), or place them inside an initialization event.